# Dropzon show Error uploading photos:The upload path does not appear to be valid

Tags: javascript, php, dropzone

**When I try to upload photos using Dropzone, the error message mentioned above appears, indicating an issue with the upload path. I have double-checked the path settings in my code, and they seem to be correct. Despite this, the error persists.**

What's the reason?
I am currently working on implementing Dropzone.js for handling file uploads in my web application. However, I am encountering an issue where the error message "Error uploading photos: The upload path does not appear to be valid" is displayed.

I am using PHP codeigniter3 framework and PHPMyadmin for my backend.

```
public function uploadlandphotos()
{
    $response = array();
    $parcelnum = $this->input->post('parcelnum');
    $parcelnum = str_replace('.', '', $parcelnum);
    if (!empty($_FILES['land_photos']['name'])) {
        $upload_path = FCPATH . 'uploads/user_kyc/land_photos/';
        if (!is_dir($upload_path)) {
            if (!mkdir($upload_path, 0777, true)) {
                $response = array('msg' => 'Failed to create the upload directory', 'status' => false);
                echo json_encode($response);
                return;
            }
        }
        $config['upload_path'] = $upload_path;
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|jpeg|png|mp4|avi|mov';
        $config['max_size'] = 25600;
        $this->load->library('upload', $config);

        if ($this->upload->do_upload('land_photos')) {
            $fileData = $this->upload->data();
            $originalFileName = str_replace(' ', '_', $fileData['file_name']);
            $newFileName = $parcelnum . '_' . $originalFileName;
            $newFilePath = $upload_path . $newFileName;
            if (rename($fileData['full_path'], $newFilePath)) {
                $response = array('msg' => 'Photos Uploaded Successfully', 'status' => true, 'file_name' => $newFileName);
            } else {
                $response = array('msg' => 'Error renaming the file', 'status' => false);
            }
        } else {
            $error = $this->upload->display_errors();
            $response = array('msg' => 'Error uploading photos: ' . $error, 'status' => false);
        }
    } else {
        $response = array('msg' => 'No file selected', 'status' => false);
    }
    echo json_encode($response);
}
```

Comment: I was able to resolve the issue by making a modification in my server-side code. Specifically, I replaced the line:
`$this->load->library('upload', $config);` to 
`$this->upload->initialize($config);`

Comment: fyi, phpMyAdmin is "just" a tool/UI to manage your mysql servers, databases, tables etc.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve the issue by modifying my server-side code. Specifically, I replaced the line

```
$this->load->library('upload', $config); to
$this->upload->initialize($config);
```